# Copying content from a lookup field to text field in crm 2013

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to copy content from lookup field to another text field in crm 2013 (on change)
I wrote this:

```
function ChangeCateforyField() {

var typeId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('el_type_id').getValue(); //get the value from field el_type_id.
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('category').setValue(typeId);// sets the value in el_type_id field.
```

I get an error when i choose value in my lookup field (error that sais that the fiels can only get string or empty which is not suitable to the field property)

Is the code OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the right value if the field types are not the same.

From your code probably `el_type_id` is a lookup and `category` probably a text field.

In this case you can get the `.name` property of the lookup value and set inside category.

```
var typeId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('el_type_id').getValue();
if (typeId != null) {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('category').setValue(typeId[0].name);
}
```